# Adding entries into database instantly or after filling out form

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I'm working on a PHP/MySQL application that allows for organization members to be maintained within the database. Currently, upon clicking on a "Add Member" span, I insert a blank entry into the database and return the created ID to PHP. Upon receipt of a valid ID, the application user is redirected via jQuery to an edit page that refers to the newly-created member.

As far as I can tell, this has the following advantages/disadvantages:

*Advantages*

- Can instantly associate purchases/payments with a member upon submitting a jQueryUI dialog, since I already have the ID of that member.
- Unifies what would have been separate add/edit screens, so easier maintainability on my side.

*Disadvantages*

- There is a high possibility that I will have stale entries. That is, someone could click on "Add Member" multiple times and not save the new page, therefore causing entries to remain blank.
- Not able to enforce as many constraints in the table, since I need to be able to accept NULL for all of the columns.

Am I thinking of all of the scenarios/advantages/disadvantages? Should I make a separate page for adding members, or is it better to accept the stale entries, and possibly add a few checks when I fetch all members to make sure that I'm not displaying a stale entry?

My database function for adding members currently:

```
public static function addMember()
{
    $q = 'INSERT INTO ' . MemberTable::TABLE_NAME
            . ' (' . MemberTable::ID
            . ') VALUES (null)';
    try
    {
        $db = new DBConnection();
        $toRet = $db->execute($q);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        $toRet = -1;
    }
    if($toRet > 0)
    {
        DBSystemEvent::logMessage("Added new member with ID $toRet");
    }
    unset($db);
    return $toRet;
}
```

**EDIT 1:** After rereading the question, I need to clarify that members and users referred to in the first paragraph are different. Users refer to the person logged into the application. Members are not able to log into the application. This is similar to a hospital application (patients may not log in or edit their own information; only application users such as nurses or doctors may log in and edit information).

**EDIT 2:** While none of the given answers completely fit my problem (since I may have to insert into the database without knowing an ID), I decided to accept an answer based on how my question was worded (since making it any more specific may cross into too-localized territory).

Comment: Why not just use the edit page as an add/edit page? If it's filled out with no ID set then it adds and if it's filled out with an ID set then it edits?

Comment: @MichaelRushton - I had done that in an earlier iteration of this application. However, if the ID is set but there is no member with that ID, editing wouldn't work (since an UPDATE would affect 0 rows). That being said, I'd already be fetching the member at the top, and I could basically unset the ID if the member couldn't be found...

Comment: Why not transact the whole process? If they fail to finish just abort.

Comment: You don't set the ID if there's no member with that ID. You'll have `edit.php?id=0` rather than `edit.php?id=1` (and when submitting the form if `id == 0` then you `INSERT` rather than `UPDATE`).

Comment: If he saves purchases to database with user's ID then having ID=0 can mix data between 2 simultaneous new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little bit unclear to me what exactly is the workflow of your site.
If user comes to you page then I assume that he must login from where you get his ID. If he  is new user then he is redirected to userdata.php?id=0 where he enters his data. After submitting you should check if $id=0 and if the user with the same username/id/.. exists (SELECT... WHERE ID=xxx) and warn user to change his username. If no match is found then you can do INSERT and obtain the new ID.

If in future user wants to change his data then after login you can direct him to userdata.php?id=123 (where 123 is his ID). Then you can check if $id>0 and do UPDATE.

Comment: I edited my question to better clarify the difference between users and members.

Comment: That makes it clearer, but same logic remains - have the same form for update/insert and send a ID as parameter to it.  Just like Michael suggested. Your worry about ID that doesn't exist is groundless because either the ID is obtained from member selection or is created during INSERT by autoincrement.

Comment: Ok then, I'm still worried that this would make the logic for managing member payments/purchases more convoluted. As I see it, I'd use a temporary ID for each payment/purchase so that I can add/delete payments and purchases on the page using JavaScript and using a hidden input field so that I can tell which temporary IDs are available to get PHP-side. Would this be correct?

Comment: Why use temporary ID (I assume that you are talking about member's ID) - use real one. If you are talking about purchase ID then these are totally unrelated and you can get them from autoincrement field of purchases table. If user make the purchase then you can mark these records as final. Otherwise you can periodically go through the table and delete non-final records that are older than for example 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common problem - you need to know the ID before INSERT, but it's known only after. So there is only one adequate solution: use GUID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) instead of autoincrement ID. Generate guid from PHP code, for example `com_generate_guid()`, and do not preINSERT empty rows at all. And make relations between tables with GUID fields.

Comment: I would say this answer is the best, because you should never in my opinion insert thing into db, that you may never use. When the db-structure (a column with null-fields) is dependent of functionality in the code, it just can't be right. But a little note on the answer: It's com_create_guid() for PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, switch to postgresql. This will allow you to use a sequence to provide you with a unique ID without entering empty entities into you database. 
Funny enough one of my clients is using the same approach you haven chosen and so far this lead to a lot of maintenance and work load overhead to weed out the empty entries from the db.

If you cannot use a database that offers sequences consider using an otherwise empty table which only atomically gives you unique ids. That way you can already start using the id to prepare relations on the client side and then enter them in bulk into the db when the member is finally created.